# Scala Oracle JDBC

Tags: oracle, scala, jdbc

I am getting a `Module not found` error in Scala. I am trying to get a jdbc connection to Oracle, join two tables and then print it out.

My scala file is

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

object sparkJDBC {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple      
        Application").setMaster("local[2]").set("spark.executor.memory","1g")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    var sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
    val chrttype = sqlContext.load("jdbc", 
      Map("url" -> "jdbc:oracle:thin:gductv1/gductv1@//localhost:1521/XE",
      "dbtable" -> "chrt_typ"))
    val clntlvl1  = sqlContext.load("jdbc", 
      Map("url" -> "jdbc:oracle:thin:gductv1/gductv1@//localhost:1521/XE", 
      "dbtable" -> "clnt_lvl1"))
    val join2 =  
      chrttyp.join(clntlvl1,chrttyp.col("chrt_typ_key")===clntlvl1("lvl1_key"))
    join2.foreach(println)
    join2.printSchema()
    }
}
```

My build.sbt file is

```
   name := "sparkJDBC"
   version := "0.1"
   scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

   libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.5.1" 
   libraryDependencies += "org.apache.tika" % "tika-core" % "1.11"
   libraryDependencies += "org.apache.tika" % "tika-parsers" % "1.11"
   libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "2.7.1" 
   libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql" % "1.0.0"
```

The error file is

```
[warn]  module not found: org.apache.spark#spark-sql;1.0.0
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\.ivy2\local\org.apache.spark\spark-sql\1.0.0\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-sql/1.0.0/spark-sql-1.0.0.pom
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.apache.spark#spark-sql;1.0.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-sql;1.0.0: not found
```

Please help me figure out what's causing this.

Comment: problem: current Resolver does not have dependencies you're asking

Answer (score 0):

`spark-sql` is a Scala library, like `spark-core`, so you need `%%` between group name and artifact name in the same way. Use `%` between them only for Java libraries. See http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Cross-Build.html for the reason you need `%%`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be sure to have a correct dependency, you can use website like mvnrepository : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql_2.10/1.0.0

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.10" % "1.0.0"
```

Comment: That was a great pointer Thomas. I do not have a 'Module not found' issue any more, but here is the error now      [error] Modules were resolved with conflicting cross-version suffixes in {file:/C:/apps/spark-2.1.0/ScalaFiles/}scalafil
es:
[error]    org.json4s:json4s-ast _2.11, _2.10
[error]    com.twitter:chill _2.11, _2.10
[error]    org.json4s:json4s-jackson _2.11, _2.10
[error]    org.json4s:json4s-core _2.11, _2.10
[error]    org.apache.spark:spark-core _2.11, _2.10

Comment: I removed the Scala Version reference in the .sbt file (scalaVersion := "2.11.7") and it then did not give me any conflicting cross-version. Now it is give me some SQLContext error, but it is past the first hurdle. Thanks to Thomas and Alexey for the quick response.